# MobileMe calendar invite emails are missing Accept/Decline buttons

Tags: mobileme

I've got a weird problem that is almost certainly a configuration issue. I send calendar requests to 3 people via MobileMe (for shared calendaring), and 2 of the people receive Accept/Decline buttons in their HTML emails (and also an ICS file), but one does not.

I've checked all sorts of settings, but I can't figure out why he doesn't get the Accept/Decline buttons or ICS attachments when the others do!

Any ideas?

Comment: Pretty weird. I cant thing of a reason why it wouldn't work... perhaps your icons are too big? Are you using the 512 and 256 boxes? anyhow. If you don't get any good answer here I suggest you post your answer at http://stackoverflow.com/. That site is uniquely oriented to coding and developing, so you are most likely to find your answer there from people with more expertise on the matter.

Comment: @kevin9794: Did you misplace your comment? This question doesn't have anything to do with custom icons.

Comment: Weird. I think I might have. hahaha sorry.